# In CloudFormation how can I link RDS and Secrets Manager so I don't have to hardcode the password?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager

I'm doing a personal project and trying to not hard code a database password into a cloudformation template.

This is what I have so far:

```
  RDSPassword:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Description: Password for RDS Database
      GenerateSecretString:
        PasswordLength: 10
      Name: RDSPassword
  
  DBSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: Subnet group for RDS
      DBSubnetGroupName: RDSSubnetGroup
      SubnetIds:
        - !GetAtt PrivateSubnet1.SubnetId
        - !GetAtt PrivateSubnet2.SubnetId

  RDSDatabase:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      AllocatedStorage: 5
      AvailabilityZone: eu-west-2a
      DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
      DBName: KenobiMySQLDB
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnetGroup
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: admin
      MasterUserPassword: WHAT GOES HERE??
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt RDSSecurityGroup.GroupId
```

In "WHAT GOES HERE" I've tried:

- Fn::Sub: {{resolve:secretsmanager:${RDSPassword}::password}} (on a new line)
- !Ref RDSPassword
- !Ref RDSPassword.Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [MasterUserSecret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-dbinstance-masterusersecret.html):

```yaml
  RDSDatabase:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      AllocatedStorage: 5
      AvailabilityZone: eu-west-2a
      DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
      DBName: KenobiMySQLDB
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnetGroup
      Engine: MySQL
      MasterUsername: admin
      MasterUserSecret: 
        KmsKeyId: ...
        SecretArn: ...
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !GetAtt RDSSecurityGroup.GroupId
```

Comment: @MikeMac you're welcome, consider upvoting the answer too

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you and those who need answers to the same question in the future.
First, you can create a secret manually in the AWS console, and then pass it in the CloudFormation in a secure way.

```
MyDBInstance:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
  Properties:
    DBName: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:dev/whatever/db:SecretString:dbname}}'
    Engine: postgres
    MasterUsername: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:dev/whatever/db:SecretString:username}}'
    MasterUserPassword: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:dev/whatever/db:SecretString:dbpassword}}'
    DBInstanceClass: db.m5.large
    AllocatedStorage: 20
    DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref MyDBSubnetGroup
    VPCSecurityGroups:
      - !GetAtt DBSecurityGroup.GroupId
    MultiAZ: false
    PubliclyAccessible: false
```

Let's look at the string below:

```
{{resolve:secretsmanager:dev/whatever/db:SecretString:dbname}}
```

**dev/whatever/db** - the Secret name in AWS Secrets Manager 
**dbname,username,dbpassword** - the Key of the Secret Key. 
But the *value* of exactly this will be your little secret, which is hidden even in the picture below.

[image]